# Replace the dot after a paragraph title with a colon in ACM template

Tags: sections-paragraphs, acm

How can I replace the dot after a paragraph title in the ACM template? Currently, the template automatically adds a dot to paragraphs:

[image: paragraph]

I would rather need a colon, like this

[image: colon]

Switching the feature off did not work in the ACM document class.

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{acm_proc_article-sp}
\documentclass[numbers=noendperiod]{acm_proc_article-sp}
```

Did not have any effect.

Here is a minimal example:

```
% THIS IS SIGPROC-SP.TEX - VERSION 3.1
% WORKS WITH V3.2SP OF ACM_PROC_ARTICLE-SP.CLS
% APRIL 2009
% For tracking purposes - this is V3.1SP - APRIL 2009

\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{acm_proc_article-sp}
\begin{document}
\title{Getting Rid of Dots}
\numberofauthors{1}
\author{
\alignauthor
John Doe\\
}

\maketitle
\section{On Paragraphs and Dots}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elit.
\paragraph{Paragraph Title}
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
\balancecolumns
% That's all folks!
\end{document}
```

How could I overwrite this? Note that I use paragraph for structuring. I could use simply a bold face text instead, but this does not seem to be a clean answer. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `etoolbox`. I didn't test if there are side effects:

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{acm_proc_article-sp}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\def\paragraph{\def\@period{\upshape:}%
    \vskip 12pt\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}{6\p@ \@plus \p@}% % GM and Wolfgang May - 11/30/06
    {-5\p@}{\subsecfnt}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\title{Getting Rid of Dots}
\numberofauthors{1}
\author{
\alignauthor
John Doe\\
}

\maketitle
\section{On Paragraphs and Dots}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elit.
\paragraph{Paragraph Title}
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\balancecolumns
% That's all folks!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bernard! That did the trick! It least at first sight, I do not see any side effects!